# Sending long XML over TCP

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, tcp

I'm sending an object (class name `House`) over TCP using the `TcpListener` on the server side in response to any message received from the `TcpClient`.

When the message is received, it is currently populating a text box named `textBox1`.

If I send a line of text, it works fine.  You'll notice that I have a redundant line "Hello, I'm a server" for testing this purpose.  But when I send the XML, it is cutting it off prematurely.

When I send serialised XML in to the stream, I'm also receiving this error from the server side:

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

**Here's my server code**

```
// Set the variables for the TCP listener
Int32 port = 14000;
IPAddress ipaddress = IPAddress.Parse("132.147.160.198");
TcpListener houseServer = null;

// Create IPEndpoint for connection
IPEndPoint ipend = new IPEndPoint(ipaddress, port);

// Set the server parameters
houseServer = new TcpListener(port);

// Start listening for clients connecting
houseServer.Start();

// Buffer for reading the data received from the client
Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
String data = "hello, this is a house";

// Show that the TCP Listener has been initialised
Console.WriteLine("We have a TCP Listener, waiting for a connection...");

// Continuing loop looking for 
while (true)
{

    // Create a house to send
    House houseToSendToClient = new House
    {
        house_id = 1,
        house_number = 13,
        street = "Barton Grange",
        house_town = "Lancaster",
        postcode = "LA1 2BP"
    };

    // Get the object serialised
    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(House));

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(memoryStream, houseToSendToClient);
    }

    // Accept an incoming request from the client
    TcpClient client = houseServer.AcceptTcpClient();

    // Show that there is a client connected
    //Console.WriteLine("Client connected!");

    // Get the message that was sent by the server
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

    // Blank int
    int i;

    // Loop for receiving the connection from the client

    // >>> ERROR IS ON THIS LINE <<<
    while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("here");

        // Take bytes and convert to ASCII string
        data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);

                Console.WriteLine("Received s, return house");

                // Convert the string to a byte array, ready for sending
                Byte[] dataToSend = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello, I'm a server");

                // Send the data back to the client
                //stream.Write(dataToSend, 0, dataToSend.Length);

                // Send serialised XML in to the stream
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(stream, houseToSendToClient);

    }

    // Close the connection
    client.Close();
}
```

**Client code**

```
// Get the object serialised
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(House));

// Set the variables for the TCP client
Int32 port = 14000;
IPAddress ipaddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
IPEndPoint ipend = new IPEndPoint(ipaddress, port);

string message = "s";

try
{

    // Create TCPCLient
    //TcpClient client = new TcpClient("localhost", port);
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

    // Convert the string to a byte array, ready for sending
    Byte[] dataToSend = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

    // Connect using TcpClient
    client.Connect(ipaddress, port);

    // Client stream for reading and writing to server
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            // Send the data to the TCP Server
            stream.Write(dataToSend, 0, dataToSend.Length);
            //xmlSerializer.Serialize(stream, houseToSend);                        

            // Buffer to store response
            Byte[] responseBytes = new Byte[256];

            string responseData = String.Empty;

            // Read the response back from the server
            Int32 bytes = stream.Read(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length);
            responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseBytes, 0, bytes);
            textBox1.Text = responseData;


        // Close the stream and the client connection
        stream.Close();
        client.Close();

}
catch (SocketException e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
}
```

I've marked on the code where the error is appearing.

Is it because the message is too long?

Comment: I've just increased the buffer to 2048 and that seems to have worked... if someone can explain why this works please let me know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your client code is assuming that the entire message will come through in one call to the `Read(...)` method, which is absolutely wrong.  From the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx): *"An implementation is free to return fewer bytes than requested even if the end of the stream has not been reached."*

It's possible that, for a 1024-byte XML document, you may have to call `Read(...)` 1024 times to get the entire message.

Really, you'd do well to send a four-byte length before you send the XML, so that the client knows how much data to expect.  The client will read four bytes, convert that to an integer length, then read that many *more* bytes, then turn those bytes into XML.